# How do I make a primary key without auto-increment?

Tags: python, django, auto-increment

I've been trying to create a model that has a primary key, but I don't want that primary key to auto increment.

I know I can specify the value each time, but I want the field to be required that I specify it (hopefully enforced by the database and django), and fail fast if I forget.

It seemed logical that I would be able to say `auto_increment=False` on my field, but that isn't supported by the field :(

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create `id` field with `primary_key=True` explicitly in your model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

That way it won't be auto-incremented, but it will still be an primary key.

Comment: Awesome. I thought I tried this, but perhaps my migration wasn't working at the time. Thanks.